# Flexbox overlapping absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm trying to make a multilanguage navbar with flexbox, using some JS to toggle visibility of the elements I don't want, but am having trouble retaining the layout with absolute positioning.

Ideally I'd like .language to have absolute positioning so the multilanguage elements can invisibly overlap but applying this overrides the flexbox layout.

```
.language {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL10d4jy/)

```js
function switchLanguage(lang) {
  var languageElements = document.getElementsByClassName('language')
  for (var x in languageElements) {
    if (languageElements[x].getAttribute('lang') != lang) {
      languageElements[x].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
      languageElements[x].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }
}

switchLanguage('bs')
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>li {
  flex: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .container>li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container>li {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}

.language {
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <div class="language" lang="bs">
    <ul class="container">
      <li><a href="#about">O Nama</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hours">Radno Vrijeme</a></li>
      <li><a href="#map">Karta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meni</a></li>
      <li onclick="switchLanguage('en')">English</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="language" lang="en">
    <ul class="container">
      <li><a href="#about ">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hours ">Opening Hours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#map ">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="# ">Menu</a></li>
      <li onclick="switchLanguage('bs')">Bosanski</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Since you swap between two different sized `language` wrapper, how should the behave other than _move_ some as their content size is not the same?

Comment: instead of toggling the visibility, I would suggest toggling the width on the .language boxes using a class

Comment: the content size is the same, if you look at the fiddle you'll see they're stacked on top of each other while I want them to be stacked on top, but can't achieve this with putting position: absolute in .language without losing the flex

Comment: And how do you mean it losing the flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the width to the absolute positioned element. Without that it collapses to content size or zero if empty. It's also recommended to apply the correct offsets.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c0a1Lge/)**

```
.language {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a css class and switch between the blocks  I have used `hide` class as shown below

HTML:

```
  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="language hide" lang="bs">
      <ul class="container">
        <li><a href="#about">O Nama</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hours">Radno Vrijeme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#map">Karta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meni</a></li>
        <li onclick="switchLanguage('en')">English</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="language" lang="en">
      <ul class="container">
        <li><a href="#about ">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hours ">Opening Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#map ">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="# ">Menu</a></li>
        <li onclick="switchLanguage('bs')">Bosanski</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>li {
  flex: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .container>li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container>li {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}

.language.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

JS: Modified the JS on the JSfiddle to switch classes

```
function switchLanguage(lang) {
  var languageElements = document.getElementsByClassName('language')
  for (var x in languageElements) {
    if (languageElements[x].getAttribute('lang') != lang) {
      console.log(languageElements[x].classList);
      languageElements[x].classList.add("hide");
    } else {
      console.log(languageElements[x].classList);
      languageElements[x].classList.remove("hide");
    }
  }
}

switchLanguage('bs')
```

Please find the working code on the codepen below:
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/YexWOX

Comment: the idea was to avoid using `position:absolute`. Why is this negative. The answer is basically removing the need for `position: absolute`

Comment: It is not negative, but an unexplained answer is not of much use, so add an explanation.

Comment: Done, added explaination